# How to retrieve documents form firebase firestore according to a specific value in those documents in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure on firestore,
[image]
and I want to retrieve series documents that have the same category or genre (10 docs at a time).

```
EX: 10 series documents of category Mystery
```

I know it's done using the `where()` and `limit()` methods, but I don't know how to access the objects in the `categories array` especially when they have no names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot search for nested items within nested lists, you can however search for the exact object in the list, and in your case it's a `Map<String, String>`.

So, use this, which might\should work:

```
.where('categories', arrayContains: {"ar_title": غموض, "en_title":"Mystery"})
```

Comment: does it have to be the exact object? I mean can't I just pass the "en_title"??

Comment: Unfortunately not, because think of it from Firebase's perspective. it has a list of categories, at every index, inside it, there is `en_title`. Array contains only looks in the very first level of categories, at index0, index1..etc But what you actually need, is for it to look inside each and every index, if it contains an `en_title`, and then for that `en_title` to match `Mystery`. And currently, they don't do that.