# firebase firestore flutter where query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter a firestore list on nested array item present in data list.

[image: Fire store structure]

I  have a collection decision that contains multiple documents. You can see in picture that the document has team list and team list has one more team member list, so I have to get only those documents whose email (which is present in team_list's team_member_list field ) is equal to my email id.
How can get this in Flutter Firebase Firestore  using where clause?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('decision').orderBy('close_date')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve documents form firebase firestore according to a specific value in those documents in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212640/how-to-retrieve-documents-form-firebase-firestore-according-to-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 0):

The [`array-contains` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) of Firebase can be used to filter documents where a specific item exists in an array field, but the operation requires that you specify the complete item in the array.

There is no way to search for just a single value in an item in an array, nor in an subarray (as in your document structure).

If you want to be able to select the document based on the emails of team members, add a field with precisely those values to the documents and keep that in sync with the `teams_list` field.

Such a field would look something like this:

```
team_member_emails: ["snjmediastudio@gmail.com", "vishal@somewhere.com"]
```

Once you have that field, you can query with:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('decision')
  .where("team_member_emails", "array-contains", "snjmediastudio@gmail.com")
```